# Расставьте знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Расставьте знаки препинания в следующем тексте:

"Я снежок в ладонях заласкаю

Пусть вода сквозь пальцы потечёт

По прохладным каплям загадаю

Что мне будет нечет или чёт

Если нечет то меня коснётся

Молодым крылом своим весна

Если чёт то значит не придётся

От капели мне сходить с ума

Нечет значит буду я любима

Радуга на небе вспыхнет вновь

Ну а чёт тогда промчится мимо

Недозрелой тучкою любовь

Если нечет гимном обручальным

Стану для певца я и творца

Если чёт мелодией печальной

Песней без начала и конца

Капельки в руке какая малость

Я веду мечтам прозрачным счёт

Сколько в кулачке надежд осталось

Нечет чёт и снова нечет чёт

Под ноги упали на дорогу

Вперемешку радость и беда

И печаль уходит понемногу

Как сквозь пальцы талая вода."

Answer (score 2):

Я снежок в ладонях заласкаю -

Пусть вода сквозь пальцы потечёт.

По прохладным каплям загадаю,

Что мне будет - нечет или чёт.

Если нечет, то меня коснётся

Молодым крылом своим весна.

Если чёт, то, значит, не придётся

От капели мне сходить с ума.

Нечет - значит, буду я любима,

Радуга на небе вспыхнет вновь.

Ну, а чёт - тогда промчится мимо

Недозрелой тучкою любовь.

Если нечет - гимном обручальным

Стану для певца я и творца.

Если чёт - мелодией печальной,

Песней без начала и конца.

Капельки в руке - какая малость!

Я веду мечтам прозрачным счёт:

Сколько в кулачке надежд осталось-

Нечет, чёт, и снова нечет, чёт.

Под ноги упали на дорогу

Вперемешку радость и беда,

И печаль уходит понемногу,

Как сквозь пальцы талая вода.

Comment: А такой вариант допустим?
По прохладным каплям загадаю,
Что мне будет : нечет или чёт.

Comment: Конечно. Можно оформить и как с однородными членами и обобщающим словом, и как обособление однородных членов в конце предложения с помощью тире.